# ASP.NET MVC Search with dropdownlist in layout page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, drop-down-menu

I am stuck with very common problem, in my application I want to put search-navbar which will be available in every page.
I mean search with query to write and dropdownlist with category of item to search.

Because I want to have acces in every page, I implemented it in Layout page like below:

```
     <div class="col-xs-10 search-field">
                    @Html.Editor(" ", new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "search-input", @id = "searchQuery", @placeholder = ResourcesPolish.Search_WhatAreYouLookingFor}})
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 category-field">
                    @Html.DropDownList(" ",
                     new SelectList(new[]
                       {
                           new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "Elektronika"},
                           new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "Moda i uroda"},
                           new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "Dom i zdrowie"},
                           new SelectListItem {Value = "4", Text = "Dziecko"},
                           new SelectListItem {Value = "5", Text = "Kultura i rozrywka"},
                           new SelectListItem {Value = "6", Text = "Elektronika"},
                           new SelectListItem {Value = "7", Text = "Sport i wypoczynek"},
                           new SelectListItem {Value = "8", Text = "Motoryzacja"},
                           new SelectListItem { Value = "9", Text = "Kolekcje i sztuka"},
                           new SelectListItem {Value = "10", Text = "Firma"},
                           new SelectListItem {Value = "11", Text = "Inne"},
                       }, "Value", "Text"), "wszystkie działy", new { @class = "category-input", @id = "category" })
                </div>
<div class="col-xs-1 search-button" onclick="search()">                                   
                </div>
```

Then, I have javascript which take value, that is selected:

```
function search() {

    var categoryId = $('#category').val();
    var query = $('#searchQuery').val();
    if (query) {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("SearchItem","Item")?query=' + query + '&categoryId=' + categoryId;
    }
}
```

It work's fine, but all categories are hardcode'd, and maybe better solution is to read them from Db, because admin may change part of them? But I haven't got any way to do this via Layout page (I mean to pass them via model), so I don't know, is there any better solution for stuffs like that?
This is the same situation like at ebay.com, always at the top of the page there should be search-area with dropdown for categories. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a controller for your navbars, like this:

```
public class NavbarController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Categories()
    {
        // you might want to return this from database, of course
        var model = new SelectList(new[]
                   {
                       new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "Elektronika"},
                       new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "Moda i uroda"},
                       new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "Dom i zdrowie"},
                       new SelectListItem {Value = "4", Text = "Dziecko"},
                       new SelectListItem {Value = "5", Text = "Kultura i rozrywka"},
                       new SelectListItem {Value = "6", Text = "Elektronika"},
                       new SelectListItem {Value = "7", Text = "Sport i wypoczynek"},
                       new SelectListItem {Value = "8", Text = "Motoryzacja"},
                       new SelectListItem { Value = "9", Text = "Kolekcje i sztuka"},
                       new SelectListItem {Value = "10", Text = "Firma"},
                       new SelectListItem {Value = "11", Text = "Inne"},
                   }, "Value", "Text");
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then a separate view called `Categories.cshtml` inside a `Navbar` folder, which would look like this:

```
@model SelectList

@{ 
    Layout = null;
}

<div class="col-xs-10 search-field">
    @Html.Editor(" ", new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "search-input", @id = "searchQuery", @placeholder = ResourcesPolish.Search_WhatAreYouLookingFor}})
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 category-field">
    @Html.DropDownList(" ", Model, "wszystkie działy", new { @class = "category-input", @id = "category" })
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 search-button" onclick="search()">                                   
</div>
```

In your layout, you replace all that html with this:

```
@Html.Action("Categories", "Navbar");
```

Actually, I wouldn't use a `SelectList` as a model, it's just to show how it could work. You might want to create a `CategoriesViewModel` holding the `SelectList`, or an `IEnumerable<CategoryViewModel>` and create the `SelectList` inside your view, by using your model.

Comment: Looks fine, I tried and it throws me an StackOverFlowException in:
     @Html.Action("Categories", "Layout"); - this line in LAyout page

Comment: Take note inside `Categories.cshtml` I'm setting `Layout = null;`. Are you doing this as well? You need to do this...otherwise it would cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's right way, but also you can change your _Layout.cshtml like that:

```
 @using D.Models//namespace where your database described

    @{ db a = new db();
        SelectList list = new SelectList(a.Table/*table what you need*/, "value", "name");
    }
```

and then:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 category-field">
                    @Html.DropDownList(" ",list, "wszystkie działy", new { @class = "category-input", @id = "category" })
                </div>
```